# iOS 7 red status bar

Tags: ios, statusbar, launch

When Shazam is opened the status bar turns red and doubles it's height because of background recording, but this ruins the UI in my app. I'm now trying to change my code to support different status bar sizes, because the red status bar is also opaque, but I can't come up with a general solution because of this:

**When the status bar is initially red, when I launch my app, the launch image is scaled and ruined. How to fix this?**

Note: My app does NOT use recording.

**[Edit]**

The only solution I found was to set 'Status bar is initially hidden' to YES in .plist. I don't  really need the status bar to be visible on app launch, especially if it affects my launch image when the status bar is taller than usual, i.e. when recording or during a phone call.

**[Edit 2]**

There are cases when the launch image will be briefly visible when the app is brought to foreground from background state. To work around this I use view-controller based status bar appearance:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

This ensures the status bar is always hidden when the app comes to foreground, so the launch image will never be affected. Don't forget to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` on `appDidEnterBackground` and (inside an animation block) on `appDidBecomeActive` notifications.

Comment: All apps will have their launch images scaled in such a case. Is that your only issue?

Comment: @maddy Yeah, and it's really ugly. I don't know if it's scaled, but rather looks like a portion is being cut horizontally in the middle, because at the bottom I have the app name which still looks good.

Comment: This isn't restricted to the red status bar. It also applies to the green status bar when on a regular phone call. Your only option is to create a launch image that looks reasonable when there is a taller status bar.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that, because that would affect the launch image when the status bar is normal. I'm actually looking for a solution for my launch image to look ok in both cases, regardless the status bar height.

Comment: You have no control over it other than designing an image that looks OK when normal and when "squished".

Answer (score 3):

The red status bar is a system function. You are not going to be able to work around this - and it isn't really your 'fault' if the launch screen looks like that - if the user wants to open your app while using Shazam, they are going to see the red bar and the launch image is going to be scaled. You could change the launch image to look good when scaled, but then it would look bad the rest of the time (when the red bar wasn't at the top of the screen on launch).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, I could somehow change the image to look good when status bar is taller, but that would only be half of solution. I would rather keep the other half of solution instead, i.e. the image when the status bar height is normal.

Answer (score 0):

After a long long long long long research and hurdles I found out simple solution for this follow as below

In Targets->General->Deployment Info check the HideStatusBar Option

like below!

[image]

And in the ViewController (Which one you kept as RootViewController) in viewDidAppear add this line of code...

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Because when you uncheck HideStatusBar Option and your app needs any background process or audio related process then the status bar will become red with enlarged height. If you dont want status bar in entire app then dont add the above line in viewDidAppear and check HideStatusBar Option.